# group_by not working with rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.0.6

```
Keyword.create(:name => 'ror')
Keyword.create(:name => 'ror')
Keyword.create(:name => 'ruby')
```

I want to find popular search keywords.

I tried the followings but it did not work

```
>Keyword.group_by('keywords.name').order('count(keywords.id) desc')
undefined method `group_by' for #<Class:0x10278d748>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 'group' instead of 'group_by'